# How to make 8.1 retargeted metro available on 8.0?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1

I was googling around in this question a bit and found only 8.0 to 8.1 answers. Is this because retargeted projects (8.1) can be downloaded and used in 8.0 windows, or because it is impossible to do?

**How can I make a 8.0 version of an app that's project was retargeted to 8.1?** Am I to have another project for 8.0 too and create two packages?

Comment: No it is not possible , as the app which is re-targeted for 8.1 would not be compatible with the versions below 8.1 . You'll have to create another package for 8.0 but yes that would be compatible with 8.1 .

Comment: Pretty uncool, but I am sure there is a reason. Would you put it as answer, so I can mark it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible , as the app which is re-targeted for 8.1 would not be compatible with the versions below 8.1 . You'll have to create another package for 8.0 but yes that would be compatible with 8.1 :) .